# Help on crowd sale contract

Tags: ico, crowdsale, truffle-contract

For a crowd sale contract can we use the etherscan API to identify the contributors and distribute the tokens, Also it will be great if someone can provide a sample contract to do the automatic distribution of tokens after the ICO.

Appreciating your valuable comments.

Thanks

Comment: No you can't use an external API in your contract. If you want to use an API, it has to be done outside the contract and you can then call the contract with the information

Answer (score 0):

OpenZeppelin have developed a [crowdsale](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol) contract. Be sure to take a look at it.

As you can see, it pays out tokens as sure as participants send Ether to the crowdsale.

You could also devise a way to have your users claim their tokens after the crowdsale has ended. That way, you could distribute the tokens proportional to the part of the total the user has contributed to the ICO.

To enable your contracts to use off-chain information, check out [Oraclize](http://www.oraclize.it/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full Python based toolchain for token sale contracts and related activities:

http://github.com/tokenmarketnet/ico

As a disclaimer this ICO repository is a sophisticated solution and basic Solidity and Python experience needed.